# How to store tires in dry California summer

Tags: tire, storage

I found an excellent deal on some tires so I bought a few. I probably won't need them for a couple of years. In Southern California the winters won't drop below 30°F but I'm more concerned about how to store my tires during the summer. I do have a garage but I think during the summer it can heat up to high 90-degree temps in there.  Also, should I keep them wrapped up in anything?

I've read that people keep them uder their bed. Climate is probably 65°–80° average in my room and no sunlight gets in under the bed. Thoughts on that location?

Comment: Mainly just keep them out of the sun, and away from any petroleum fumes.  And try to keep rainwater from collecting in them.

Answer (score 7):

UV rays and ozone are the main factors behind rubber "drying out" -- look at how the Air Force stores its airplanes in the desert: all of the rubber bits are carefully protected from the sunlight.

So try to keep it in a dry area out of the sun, and not near any ozone sources (mostly electric motors such as an AC unit).

Note that it's also important that the tire not be subject to any stress or folding that might deform it. For example, if you left the tires on your bicycle over a long period of time, they would self-deflate (due to air migrating out of the rubber) and the very bottom of the tire and tube would deform against the floor - potentially damaging the tire and its casing.

Under the bed is just fine as long as it isn't subject to any pressure or deformation that might come from it lying horizontally while deflated. Hanging the tire (while on a rim) vertically on a hook off the ceiling in a dark place is perhaps the best but might not be practical for you.

Answer (score 3):

For the tires with a foldable kevlar bead, I loosely fold them 'in four' similar to how they're packaged at the store. I haven't noticed any damage to the casings after a number of years storage in the garage.

I do not think that this is something that you need worry about for recent name brand tires that you plan to use within ~5 years. If in doubt, store in a dark location at room temperature.